# NavigationService.navigate null reference exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm learning WP coding and I have problem that I can't solve :/

```
try
 {
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/edit.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(),"Error!",MessageBoxButton.OK);
 }
```

edit.xaml is in the same directory as MainPage.xaml

It throws "NullReferenceException"

Comment: I guess you're calling this code from `MainPage`? Could you show us the full callstack? (just copy/paste the contents of `ex.ToString()`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you get an `NullReferenceException`, my guess is that you are trying to call `NavigationService.Navigate` to early, for example in the MainPage constructor.

Instead, if you want to navigate immedietly when page is loaded for example, try doing it by overriding the `OnNavigatedTo` event by adding this code to the MainPage class:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this....
This  solved my problem.

```
this.Loaded += (a, b) => {my code}
```

Comment: This worked for me, I just wanted to ask if there are any implications from doing it this way?

Answer (score 3):

This solve the problem:

```
(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/edit.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```