# How To navigate from cs class to xaml page (windows phone)

Tags: windows-phone-8, navigation

I want to navigate from my cs class to my xaml main page.
i tried it with:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Contacts.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

but i get a error: system nullreferenceexception ;

How can i navigate to my mainpage

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to call NavigationService.Navigate too early, for example, in Page constructor.

See [NavigationService.navigate null reference exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666075/navigationservice-navigate-null-reference-exception).