# WPF Navigation C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am very new to C# and the WPF Architecture. I am trying to create an application with simple page Navigation. I have changed my MainWindow from Window to NavigationWindow. I have also put the following code in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public void View(string newView) 
{
    Uri View = new Uri(newView, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    this.Navigate(View);

}
```

I am calling this method from a button in the original source:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string View;
    View = "Pages/UserAdd.xaml";
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.View(View);
}
```

However when I click the button nothing happens. I have used BreakPoints and the method is definitely called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are new to WPF, i do suggest to read about MVVM pattern https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/ first. Most of the wpf applications follow this pattern

Comment: there is a very nice blog https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/ which you can refer

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
public void View(string newView) 
{
     NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
     nav.Navigate(new Uri(View ,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

Comment: It is throwing an exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Acounting.exe

Comment: for answer of how to deal with this problem look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666075/navigationservice-navigate-null-reference-exception