# How we redirect the Page to MainPage.xaml

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, redirect

I need to Redirect to MainPage.xaml from LogInPage in silverlight Application .I use the Following ways,

```
((LogInPage)App.Current.RootVisual).ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/ShowQueue", UriKind.Relative));

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage", UriKind.Relative));
```

But I didnt achieve?Its getting Error.

Comment: what is the error ? new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)

Comment: I got NullReferenceException

Comment: if that Is the code can you add to /MainPage just .xaml  /MainPage.xaml

Comment: @Nikolay I use  NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));.But still I receive the same Error

Comment: ok see this article may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666075/navigationservice-navigate-null-reference-exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Code in App.xaml.cs file:

```
Grid rootvisual = new Grid(); 
        public void GotoPage(UserControl nextPage) 
        { 
            App app = (App)Application.Current; 
            app.rootvisual.Children.Clear(); 
            app.rootvisual.Children.Add(nextPage); 
        } 

        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) 
        { 
            this.RootVisual = rootvisual; 
            rootvisual.Children.Add(new LoginPage());  
        }
```

Then call `GotoPage(new MainPage())` in login Page. Or using `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`