# WPF page's NavigationService is null. How do I get a NavigationService on my page?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to navigate in code from one page to another:

```
if (Game.IsShopping)
    NavigationService.Navigate("ShopPage.xaml", Game.CurrentShop);
```

However I get a null reference exception on NavigationService saying that property of my current page is null. Why is this? How do I get a navigation service on my page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a solution [elsewhere on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28751806/1159763): I created a wrapper for NavigationService:

```
public static class Navigator
{
    private static NavigationService NavigationService {get;} = (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).mainFrame.NavigationService;

    public static void Navigate(string path, object param = null)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), param);
    }

    public static void GoBack()
    {
        NavigationService.GoBack();
    }

    public static void GoForward()
    {
        NavigationService.GoForward();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up a frame first (in xamel mainwindow to be rendered there)

```
<DockPanel>
    <Frame x:Name="mainFrm" />
</DockPanel>
```

then use navigate  , hence the null reference exception

```
mainFrm.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("ShopPage.xaml", Game.CurrentShop));
```

or use below if you are inside a controller action code block

```
void ExampleControllButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("ShopPage.xaml", Game.CurrentShop));
}
```

Comment: I can't access the frame in my window from the pages contained in the frame. Do I need to put the call to NavigationService elsewhere? If so, how would I call it from the pages? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: just add the dockpanel tag that contain a frame  as above , then call the frame , make sure there is no "grid" tag , then just make that call mainFrm.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("ShopPage.xaml", Game.CurrentShop)); , you can call it from any other controller as i showed you above , "this" instead of frame , it depends on your case

Comment: Why does adding a DockPanel make the Frame accessible to pages? That seems really weird...

Comment: UI elements in Docker panel are in  "Children property" that's why

Answer (score 0):

if frame element in main window add this to MainWindow.xaml.cs :

```
public static NavigationService NavigationService => ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).frmMain.NavigationService;
```

**Note**: frmMain is the name of Frame in XAML File

```
<Frame x:Name="frmMain" />
```

how to use it :

```
MainWindow.NavigationService.Navigate("ShopPage.xaml", Game.CurrentShop);
```